# Javascript/Jquery change anchor link using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, anchor

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html#section1">Natural Beauty</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#section2">Beginings</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#section3">Earth's Purity</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#section4">Bottling Goodness</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#section5">Drink to Health</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#section6">Minerals</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

I looked for possible js/jquery on how to jump into page like in the href, but the header will print just index.html.
I tried to change the href like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').each(function(){
        var value = $(this).attr('href');
        var x = 'index.html'+ (#[a-z\d-]+);
        $(this).attr('href', value.replace(x,'index.html'));
    });
});
```

It didn't work out, because the header still print index.html#section. Really need help here. Thanks

Comment: check your console. You'll see errors there

Comment: What exactly your link should look like?

Comment: it should print index.html regardless whats behind the #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use RegExp constructor when concatenating two regex patterns. Change the below statements,

```
var x = 'index.html'+ (#[a-z\d-]+);
$(this).attr('href', value.replace(x,'index.html'));
```

to,

```
$(this).attr('href', value.replace(/index\.html#[a-z\d-]+/,'index.html'));
```